# Equality of negated True/False and None

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

When implementing a board game, a board cell can be in one of the three different possible states available: True (cell occupied by first player), False (cell occupied by second player) or None (cell is empty).

My question is that:

Why does

```
not(True) == None 
return True
```

whereas that it should actually `return False`?

And why does

```
not(False) == None 
return True
```

whereas that it should actually `return False`?

Could this be a possible bug in Python that should be reported up to the developers, whom from among them, as soon as possible?

Comment: `not` is not a function. Those parentheses don't control its argument grouping. This is one of the reasons people say not to put parentheses around operator arguments as if they were functions.

Comment: Also note, you cannot return multiple values, you return a single value, a `tuple`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`not` is not a function, and `not(True)` is not a function call.

`not(True) == None` is parsed as `not (True == None)`, because `not` has lower precedence than `==`.

Please keep Python's [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in mind when writing expressions, and don't treat things like functions if they're not functions.